# Unable to get the desired clip cut in the Layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to Make the Layout as per Shown Image.

I Got Most part of the Layout Right, Just stuck with the Top Arc Clip.

[image]

Tried Code:

```
ClipPath(
            clipper: new DialogonalClipper(),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              child: Text(
                "Sign Up",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35.0,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),

              color: const Color(0xFF6d27ff),
              //color: const Color(0xFF582dff),
              height: 150.0,
            ),
          ),
```

`DialogonalClipper`  Class Code:

```
class DialogonalClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 30.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

But the result I got with the Above Code is - [image]

Comment: ```path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);``` ==> this is not a line. Use an curve instead.